# Converting json objects to csv using Twitter API in Python (adding username and description)

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I want to collect tweets with the Twitter API (Academic Access) and I just want to add the username, name and the description to the csv and it just doesn't work. I could really need some help, thank you in advance!

This is the code:

```
def create_url(keyword, start_date, end_date, max_results = 10):

search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all" #Change to the endpoint you want to collect data from

#change params based on the endpoint you are using
query_params = {'query': keyword,
                'start_time': start_date,
                'end_time': end_date,
                'max_results': max_results,
                'expansions': 'author_id,in_reply_to_user_id,geo.place_id',
                'tweet.fields': 'id,text,author_id,in_reply_to_user_id,geo,conversation_id,created_at,lang,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,reply_settings,source',
                'user.fields': 'id,name,username,created_at,description,public_metrics,verified',
                'place.fields': 'full_name,id,country,country_code,geo,name,place_type',
                'next_token': {}}
return (search_url, query_params)

def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params, next_token = None):
params['next_token'] = next_token   #params object received from create_url function
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, params = params)
print("Endpoint Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
return response.json()

def append_to_csv(json_response, fileName):

#A counter variable
counter = 0

#Open OR create the target CSV file
csvFile = open(fileName, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

#Loop through each tweet
for tweet in json_response['data']:
    
    # Create a variable for each since some of the keys might not exist for some tweets

    # 1. Author ID
    author_id = tweet['author_id']
    
    # 2. Author Username
    username = tweet['username']
    
    # 3. Author name
    name = tweet['name']
    
    # 4. Author Description
    description = tweet['description']

    # 5. Time created
    created_at = dateutil.parser.parse(tweet['created_at'])
    
    # 6. Tweet text
    text = tweet['text']

    # 7. Geolocation
    if ('geo' in tweet):   
        geo = tweet['geo']['place_id']
    else:
        geo = " "

    # 8. Tweet ID
    tweet_id = tweet['id']

    # 9. Language
    lang = tweet['lang']

    # 10. Tweet metrics
    retweet_count = tweet['public_metrics']['retweet_count']
    reply_count = tweet['public_metrics']['reply_count']
    like_count = tweet['public_metrics']['like_count']
    quote_count = tweet['public_metrics']['quote_count']

    # 11. source
    source = tweet['source']
    
    # Assemble all data in a list
    res = [author_id, username, name, description, created_at, text, geo, tweet_id, lang, like_count, quote_count, reply_count, retweet_count, source]
    
    # Append the result to the CSV file
    csvWriter.writerow(res)
    counter += 1

# When done, close the CSV file
csvFile.close()
```

The Problem is in section append_to_csv, as I get a KeyError for username, name and description. Do you have an idea what I have to change in #2, 3, and 4 to be able to add these columns to my csv? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: as you already wrote in a comment, some keys may not exist in tweet data, so you have to check if it is the case: `username = tweet['username'] if "username" in tweet else None` or using get() `username = tweet.get("username", None)`

Comment: But there should be a username for every tweet or at least most of them, and if I use the if statement I get no results at all in that column... Does it maybe have to do something with the dictionary query_params, where I maybe have to refer to user.fields somehow?